# A Strange Behavior in Adobe Illustrator CC (Version 17.0.0)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, information-graphics

I have the following problem with Illustrator (with a small number of files). I open the EPS file from Illustrator and I translate the figure in Greek. Then, I save the file. The problem is that after the closing of the file, any subsequent attempt to open the file again, displays the message

Can't open Illustrator

In other words, the program is not able to open a file that previously has been saved via exactly the same program !!! Any idea? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Hi.Welcome to GDSE. What are you saving it as?  EPS or AI?  Also why are you using EPS?  Have you tried saving as AI instead?

Comment: The fule may have corruptred on save, not common but possible

Comment: Are you saving to a server? That's a huge no-no. Never save to a server. Save locally, then copy to the server.

Comment: Did you try changing to a different font?  With special glyphs, a corrupt font might be corrupting the whole file.